# What's the algorithm to generate a modulus and a base for a Diffie-Hellman key exchange app?

Tags: key-exchange, diffie-hellman

I have a school project in which I have to write a java console application that can be used for key exchange between two people. All is fine and well, but finding good base and modulus seems to be a difficult task, especially for someone with not much mathematical background, such as myself.

I know that the two numbers have to be prime but I don't seem to be able to find any algorithm for automatically generating them. Apparently, Java has a class for it (DHParameterSpec), but I'm supposed to implement this on my own. I've read other threads on the topic, but I've found none that I can understand well.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method to generate the DH modulus and base (collectively called the "DH parameters") is to use values which have already been generated. This does not imply security issues -- several people can share the same DH parameters without trusting each other.

Technically, you need *three* values: the modulus *p*, the base *g*, and the sub-group order *q*. Ideally, *q* should be a prime integer, and *g*<sup>*q*</sup> = 1 mod *p*.

There are nice pre-generated values in [RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526) and [RFC 5114](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5114).

---

If you want to make your own, then the basic algorithm is "try random values until you hit a prime", but there are details. You have basically two choices:

1. Generate random *q* values and compute *p* = 2​_q_+1; do that until both *q* and *p* are prime. When you have found a *q* and *p* with these characteristics, then you can use *g* = 4 as base; it is guaranteed that *g* will have order exactly *q*.
2. Generate random *q* values of the "right size" for a sub-group order (say, 256 bits) until you find a prime *q*. Then generate random values *r* and compute *p* = *qr*+1 for each *r*; do that until you find a prime *p*. At that point, generate a random value *h* and compute *g* = *h*<sup>*r*</sup> mod *p*. That value *g* will have order *q* (it is theoretically possible but in practice highly improbable that you get *g* = 1; in that case, generate a new random *h*).

The first method allows the use of a very small *g*, which gives a slight performance advantage when using Diffie-Hellman (not a big advantage in practice, something like a +15% speed at most when proper optimizations have been applied). However, generating the modulus *p* with that method is quite expensive, because you have to try about a few millions of *q* values until you find one such that both *p* and *q* are prime.

With the second method, parameter generation is a lot faster, since it goes in two stages: first finding a prime *q* (a few hundred tries), then a prime *p* (a few thousand tries). It also gives you a relatively small sub-group order, which can be nice too. However, you end up with a "huge" base *g*. This method is really what is done in DSS, as specified in [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf), so if you want a formal specification with all the details laid out, go read appendix A of that standard ("Generation and Validation of FFC Domain Parameters").

In any case, you will need computations on big integers, including modular exponentiations and primality tests. Java provides both in `java.math.BigInteger`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what has to be done now.

Comment: I have an issue. I think 256 bits might be too much for the prime number q since whenever I try to calculate p, I get a negative value.

Comment: _All_ of this is about integers which are "big", i.e. quite bigger than what can fit in an `int` or a `long`. You should have `BigInteger` everywhere in your code.

Comment: I understand that and I do, but for some reason I still get a negative modulus such as: 

Large prime num: 62922831596778141152094421595998779930080421720286658690885601325815534595093
Modulus: -100967936633159750480197855067683103173782345578795306989399796028054527178237418468437

The modulus is the result of (_randLargePrime,multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(_rand.nextInt())).add(valueOf(1)) as in p = qr + 1 . I hope that makes sense.

Comment: By the way, for finding the large prime number (q) I use some code I found on wikipedia (I think it can be freely used). The name of the algorithm is Miller-Rabin. I tested my resulted q on a website that checks for prime numbers and the code seems to do its job.

Comment: I suppose your `_rand` is an instance of `java.util.Random` (or a subclass thereof) and its `nextInt()` method can return negative values. In any case, for DH to be reasonably secure, you need _q_ to be at least 200 bits or so, and _p_ to be at least 2048 bits, so the random _r_ value cannot be simple integer; that one _also_ must be a `BigInteger`.

Comment: I understand, I'll give it a shot, thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright, your idea solved my problem with negative modulus. However, when I get to the final phase of the algorithm (calculating the base) I need to compute g = h^r mod p . Is h a big number? Even if it isn't, it is impossible to raise a BigInteger to another BigInteger in java (and r is an BigInteger as you mentioned before). What do I do in this case? There is no point into trying to get r.longValue() since the number is huge.

Comment: _Everything_ is a `BigInteger` in all of this. And the exponentiation is done modulo _p_ (that's what the "mod" means) so what you want is a _modular_ exponentiation. Java's `BigInteger` provides methods for modular operations. (In fact you should really try to look up a bit on the underlying mathematics, it would explain a lot of things and that would make the exercise a lot more relevant. Google up the "handbook of applied cryptography" and read chapter 2.)

Comment: Alright, problem solved using .modPow . I should have been more attentive indeed.